# In WritableBitmap. How can i use Unlockbit,Stride in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Can i use Bitmap, Bitmapdata object in silverlight.
 And as i am using WritableBitmap.
 How can i use Unlockbit,Stride,
bitmapdata.Scan0,Methods for Writable bitmap class.

My goal is to do following in Silverlight ,

```
    bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
    bitmapdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = bitmapdata.Stride;
    IntPtr ptr = bitmapdata.Scan0;
    byte* numPtr = (byte*) ptr;
    int width = bitmap.Width;
    numPtr = (byte*) ptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Those methods don't exist on the [Silverlight WritableBitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28VS.95%29.aspx).